# Update multiple connection strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that was created by an ex-colleague, that contains a huge amount of sheets that connect to an external database. Once a month I have to go in and refresh all the tables. However every few months I have to change my database password, which means I need to go into the table properties and update the connection string, which is incredibly tedious and time consuming.

Without recreating the whole file, is there a way to quickly update all of the connection strings in the file?

Every connection string is the same:

```
DSN=DBNAME;UID=username;PWD=password;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=DBNAME;TXNISOLATION=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [Name](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/names-in-formulas.html) in excel. Assuming you have a quoted string: `"DSN=DBNAME;UID=username;PWD=password;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=DBNAME;TXNISOLATION=1;"`

You can define names for user and password (e.g. `MyUser and MyPass`) and use them like this:
`"DSN=DBNAME;UID="&MyUser&";PWD="&MyPass&";MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=DBNAME;TXNISOLATION=1;"`

Then you just need to update the names once.